# 絆｛ほだ｝す = to bind/shackle, yet referring to someone betraying?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words, word-usage

From "Granblue Fantasy: Relink" (where the English subs takes extreme liberties).

For context: A-kun works with Villain-san against MC-kun's party. But after seeing all the bad shit, A-kun has a change of heart and starts working with MC-kun. When A-kun+MC's party confront Villain-san, Villain-san says "[A-kun]、まさか絆｛ほだ｝されたと？", which is translated as "[A-kun]...is this betrayal?"

But when I look up "絆｛ほだ｝す", it apparently means to bind or shackle. How does that imply that A-kun is betraying Villain-san? For the record, there's no indication that anyone believes A-kun is being "shackled" by MC-kun's party. It's completely clear to everyone that he's acting upon his own free will to work with MC-kun's party against Villain-san.

If you want to see the line in context (warning, Granblue Fantasy Relink final battle spoilers): https://youtu.be/H2HM6hlsN2I?t=2255

Edit: apparently 絆｛ほだ｝される has a special extra definition beyond being a passive version of 絆｛ほだ｝す. It apparently can mean "to be moved by, be touched by, be overcome by". So my guess is that Villain-san was roughly saying "to think you were moved by MC-kun's party...", which does indeed make sense with the context of the story. But my question still stands: why is there such a disconnect between the verb 絆す and its passive form 絆される? Or is it just something that one must accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you notice, it is often used in the passive 絆される meaning *to be moved/touched*. You can see it in [dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%B5%86%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B/#jn-204308) [entries](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E7%B5%86%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B/#je-70424).

Since the passive usage is far more common, I think you can just remember it as *to be moved* etc, but note 大辞泉 (the first link) says:

> １ 情に引きつけられて、心や行動の自由が縛られる。「けなげな気持ちに—・れる」

So, it is the passive of *to bind* = *to be bound* and the agent (binder) is always the implicit *emotion* or *empathy*.

As you can see in the examples of the second link, it is usually used in the context where reason and emotion conflicts in a way; the subject does (not do) something against their reason due to the emotion.

Just taking one example,

> 子供への愛情にほだされて彼女は離婚に踏み切れなかった
> Because of her love for her children, she was unable to seek a divorce.

This suggests 彼女 wants to divorce by reason, but bound by considerations for her child(ren), she was unable to do it.

Similarly in your sentence, the A-kun did something (he is not supposed to do) because of his(?) feeling for MC.